# Get row where column2 is X and column1 is max of column1

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table like this:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
1     ABC   Bill
2     CDE   Fred
3     FGH   Jack
4     CDE   June
```

I would like to find the row containing a Col2 value of CDE which has the max Col1 value i.e. in this case June.  Or, put another way, the most recently added row with a col2 value of CDE, as Col1 is an auto increment column.  What is an SQL query string to achieve this?  I need this to be efficient as the query will run many iterations in a loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Iterations? Why? Please explain how you will use this. Perhaps you need no iterations and loops, just one query.

Comment: Because I am adding data conditionally, dependent on the result of the query e.g. if DataToBeAdded = LastEntry Then Discard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col2='CDE' ORDER BY col1 DESC LIMIT 1
```

in case if col1 wasn't an increment it would go somewhat like

```
SELECT *,MAX(col1) AS max_col1 FROM table WHERE col2='CDE' GROUP BY col2 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: +1 for the first query. I don't know what to comment about the second, seems erroneous ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT MAX(col1) MAXID, col2
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY col2
) t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.maxID AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
WHERE t1.col2 = 'CDE';
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ca38/9)<sup>1</sup>

---

1: <sup>This demo is mysql, but it should work fine with the same syntax in sqlite.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery such as:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM table
WHERE Col1 = (SELECT MAX(Col1) FROM table WHERE Col2='CDE')
```

Add indexes as appropriate, e.g. clustered index on Col1 and another nonclustered index on Col2 to speed up the subquery.

Answer (score -1):

In SQLite 3.7.11 and later, the simplest query would be:

```
SELECT *, max(Col1) FROM MyTable WHERE Col2 = 'CDE'
```

As shown by [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html), both this and passingby's query are most efficient, if there is an index on `Col2`.

---

If you'd want to see the correspondig values for *all* `Col2` values, use a query like this instead:

```
SELECT *, max(Col1) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Col2
```